# Why ApplyAuthenticationToRequest' is not supported by the language in .net 4.0?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have tried to download documents from Google drive. authenticator.ApplyAuthenticationToRequest(request); when i build application it give ApplyAuthenticationToRequest is not supported why? How do i remove such a error?

Comment: What's your lib version? Are you sure that you are using something implements `Google.Apis.Authentication.IAuthenticator`?

Comment: region Assembly Google.Apis.dll, v4.0.30319

Comment: @Barchu Google.Apis" version="1.5.0-beta" targetFramework="net40" /